# backward compatibility of pickled objects

Tags: python

I have a report object in python. Once the report is finalized, it must be frozen so I store it in let's say a pickled dump on the disk.
The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I might want to change the report data structure in the future and the new pickles will have different properties...but I need to be able to reload and display old reports as well as the new ones.
I think I can version my report viewer and load it with respect to the version like this:

```
data = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
if data.version == 1:
    import report_viewer1 as report_viewer
if data.version == 2:
    import report_viewer2 as report_viewer
else:
    import report_viewer # latest
```

What do you guys suggest?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: How complex is your report object? If it's not too complex, I might be inclined to serialize it to JSON (or XML, or whatever) instead of pickling it.

Comment: This sounds like an API decision. If it were me, I'd consider the object responsible for knowing how to get its data into a known format (I'd use JSON, but YMMV), then have the report viewer know how to parse that JSON into a report. If the data changes, it is required to stay backwards compatible or else it breaks the API. If you need to introduce a breaking change, your versioning check goes in the `report_viewer` module so it's transparent to the user.

Comment: In terms of format, I thought about this. I don't really see any benefit from using json/xml versus a binary file especially since there are also image objects in the report. Regarding "serialize the versioning", I did not quite understand. Please elaborate. Thanks all.